# SQL Query for string match in Obj-c

Tags: sql, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ WHERE exposureNuclides = %@", table, sourceNuclides];
```

exposureNuclides is the correct column name, sourceNuclides logs the correct string. Yet there is no match and no returns. However, if I write it like;

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@", table];
```

I get the full return as you'd expect. There is an issue between WHERE column_name = $string am I using the wrong comparison type by using `=` operator?

```
3 =     {
    exposureCiMins = "125.66";
    exposureDescription = "Man way Door";
    exposureNuclides = Ir192;
    id = 4;
};
```

as you can see, no trailing spaces.

Comment: Are you searching in the table exact match of string or substring?

Comment: Exact match, the current string presented is Ir192, it's in the table as Ir192.

Comment: Perhaps UTF8String is the issue?

Comment: Can you check trailing spaces in your database table?

Comment: @fabulaspb I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean. However, the way they're added is from hard-code not user-input. So, there shouldn't be any spaces before/after/during the string.

Comment: @fabulaspb updated the OP.

Comment: If you rewrite statement `NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ WHERE exposureNuclides = %@", table, sourceNuclides];` to `NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ WHERE exposureNuclides = 'Ir192'", table];` you will have output?

Comment: @fabulaspb Yes, that gives output.

Comment: Easy fix.. the apostrophes were the issue.. My god, thought it would be something a little more difficult. You can add your answer and I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add apostrophes to your SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM %@ WHERE exposureNuclides = '%@'
```